# Having an Issue with Angular validation

Tags: angular, typescript

can someone help me why I keep having the falling issue?

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions'.

```js
export class AddContactFormComponent implements OnInit {
  public isShowForm:boolean = false;
  
  public addContactForm: FormGroup;

  public showFrom(): void{
    this.isShowForm = true;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addContactForm = new FormGroup(controls: {
      name: new FormControl(null,{validators:[Validators.required]}),
      phone: new FormControl(null,{validators:[Validators.required]}),
    })
  }

}
```

```html
<button class="add-contact" *ngIf="!isShowForm" (click)="showFrom()">Add new contact</button>

<form action="" *ngIf="isShowForm" [formGroup]="addContactForm">
  <div class="form__body">
    <div class="form__group">
      <label for="">Name</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" formContralName="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form__group">
      <label for="">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" formContralName="phone">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form__footer">
    <button type="sumbit" class="submit">create contact</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It was supposed to be the "following" issue (rushed a bit)

Comment: you can edit your question. in the html shouldn't it be `formControl` not `formContral`?

Comment: Just use `new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])` syntax

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" formContralName="phone"> 

formContralName change to "formControlName"

Comment: @depperm thank you for pointing  it out, I did change it to control, now the  problem became name doesn't exist in validation form which it actually does :sad emoji

Comment: @TonyMarko Thank for you comment, I tried that as well now shows :

  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions'.

Comment: Try to remove controls: from new FormGroup(controls:

Answer (score 1):

Please use angular's formBuilder. It is very useful for this.

Example:

```
this.addContactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  phone: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

of course, you have to inject the formBuilder: FormBuilder to your constructor.

You can still create the form the way you did it, but I guess you have a syntax error.